# Can´t get htmlproof to accept an ignore pattern

Tags: ruby, jekyll, travis-ci

I´ve written a jekyll ci script for travis-ci.org but using jeyklll itself and htmlproof (gem html-proofer)

I can´t get the ignore pattern to work. I´m trying to ignore all files in a subfolder

```
htmlproof ./_site  --file-ignore ".+/ios/cocoadocs.+"
```

but I´m still getting plenty of errors:

```
- ./_site/ios/cocoadocs/0.7.0/Classes/SBSDKManager.html
  *  linking to internal hash #//api/name/authorizationStatus that does not exist (line 875)
  *  linking to internal hash #//api/name/authorizationStatus that does not exist (line 899)
  *  linking to internal hash #//api/name/regions that does not exist (line 336)
  *  linking to internal hash #//api/name/regions that does not exist (line 353)
```

How do I do a propper ignore pattern?

Answer (score 5):

Using http://rubular.com/ I figured out I need to escape the forward slashes and wrap in in non-escaped forward slashes:

```
htmlproof ./_site  --file-ignore "/.+\/ios\/cocoadocs.+/"
```

works